# Spell checking in IE 8

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, spell-checking

Is there any way how to programmatically (thru HTML or asp.net or C# etc) add or activate(add-on) spellchecker to IE 8 (could be also IE9 or IE10 but with doc mode IE8 ) ?
I know, that by default IE 8 dont have spellchecker included.

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/spell-check-internet-explorer-8/4b314d7b-aaa2-428f-a663-48ae235808c5

Answer (score 3):

I guess there is this however there's no real other way unfortunately.

http://www.iespell.com/